# Plesk Api 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: xml-parsing, plesk

Whenever I send the following packet to the plesk API I get the following error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable.

```
<?php
$ftpdeleterequest = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.6.0">
<ftp-user>
<del>
   <filter>
      <name>$ftpusername->name</name>
    </filter>
 </del>
</ftp-user>
</packet>
XML;
$ftpdeleteresponse = $client->request($ftpdeleterequest);
```

The packet works, it does delete the user, but still outputs the error page.

I can create and edit a ftp user without a problem, but whenever I delete the user it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching and trying I found that this problem occurs when you are trying to make a delete request from your own domain to your own domain.
https://talk.plesk.com/threads/removing-ftp-user-through-api-results-in-500-internal-server-error-php.332874/
It is a strange bug, but the problem wont occur when you are trying to delete a different domain.

Example:
Your domain is domain.tld and you have 2 domains registered in plesk: domain.tld and example.tld.
When you are trying to delete a ftp user from domain.tld you get the error, but when you delete the ftp user from example.tld there is no error.

Hope this clears it up a little for other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that php-fpm service is stopped. Check what version of php-fpm is used by domain in Plesk > Domains > domain.tld > PHP Settings. And then start it, for example for php-fpm 5.6:

/etc/init.d/plesk-php56-fpm start

Comment: php-fpm[8155]: WARNING: Nothing matches the include pattern '/opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf' from /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/p... at line 119.
php-fpm[8155]: ERROR: No pool defined. at least one pool section must be specified in config file
systemd[1]: plesk-php56-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 5.6.26 FastCGI Process Manager.
systemd[1]: Unit plesk-php56-fpm.service entered failed state.
php-fpm[8155]:  ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
php-fpm[8155]: ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Comment: So I found this: https://kb.plesk.com/en/127195 I checked to see 5.6.24 by os vendor fpm application served by apache was still running on my domain, for fun I changed the version to 5.6.26. The errors are gone in linux, but I still get the 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable when deleting an ftp user with the api. When I change it to fast-cgi I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: So I checked the log with php 5.6.26 and i found this when i delete the ftp user:
[28-Sep-2016 20:43:40] WARNING: [pool domain.tld] child 18117 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 13.362228 seconds from start
[28-Sep-2016 20:43:40] NOTICE: [pool domain.tld] child 18187 started
[28-Sep-2016 20:43:40] WARNING: [pool domain.tld] child 18187 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.011198 seconds from start
[28-Sep-2016 20:43:40] NOTICE: [pool domain.tld] child 18189 started